# Cracking any linear congruential generator

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, random-variables, factoring, totient-function

I have a **linear congruential generator** $X_{n+1} = (aX_n + b) \bmod 2^k $with given arguments and number $Y$. 
The problem is to find the smallest  $i$ that $X_i = Y$ or tell that there is no such $i$. How to solve that faster than simple approach with iterating all numbers?

Comment: I have posted an answer to this but cannot locate the previous Question at the moment.  However it has been answered by this [Security.SE post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/cracking-a-linear-congruential-generator), among other places.

Comment: Ah, it was a SciComp.SE Question and Answer I remembered, [How can I determine the initial values of pseudo-random number generator if the sequence is given?](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1845/how-can-i-determine-the-initial-values-of-pseudo-random-number-generator-if-the)

Comment: Careful reading of the body of your Question suggests a problem quite different from what the title asks.  "Cracking" would likely mean, find the parameters of the LCG, while the body of the Question assumes knowledge of the parameters and wants to find when and if a certain state will be reached.

Comment: Sorry for unclear description. By cracking i mean something lake that:i want to get value Y and lcg with known values. How many iterations my geneator has to proceed to get this number?

Comment: @hardmath So if i know parameters, is it easy to find a certain state?

Comment: I suspect this is a hard problem in general.  Setting $b=0$ we get the problem of finding what power of $a$ will give us the specified $Y$.  This suggests,equivalence in difficulty to the discrete logarithm problem mod $2^k$.